# Converting DD/MMM/YYYY date to YYYY-MM-DD - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to Select and convert a date field in the format DD/MMM/YYYY to the format YYYY-MM-DD.

I've tried a few different approaches, and in the end came up with a very ham-fisted approach of:

```
            CASE when (
            datefromparts((Right(datefield, 4)), (CASE
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JAN' then '01'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'FEB' then '02'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'MAR' then '03'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'APR' then '04'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'MAY' then '05'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JUN' then '06'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JUL' then '07'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'AUG' then '08'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'SEP' then '09'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'OCT' then '10'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'NOV' then '11'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'DEC' then '12'
            else (
            datefromparts((Right(datefield, 4)), (CASE
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JAN' then '01'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'FEB' then '02'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'MAR' then '03'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'APR' then '04'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'MAY' then '05'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JUN' then '06'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'JUL' then '07'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'AUG' then '08'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'SEP' then '09'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'OCT' then '10'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'NOV' then '11'
            when(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), datefield), 4, 3)) = 'DEC' then '12'
            else isnull(datefield,'') end), (Left(datefield, 2))))
            end [Date Field Name],
```

There's repetition due to null dates seemingly coming out as 1900-01-01.

Two questions:

What is the proper way of doing this?

This is now exporting Null results as 'NULL', but I'd rather this just be blank. Is there a way to do this?

Cheers for any help.

All the best,

Matt

Comment: Why cant you just `select cast('12/jan/2019' as date)`?

Comment: Thank you - this seems to have worked! Though when I surround with ISNULL to give ` isnull(cast(datefield as date),'')  ` this brings back 1900-01-01 where the null values would have been. Any idea how to remove these? I want these fields to be empty.

Comment: You cannot mix date datatype with varchar datatype (`''`) inside a column. SQL Server is converting `''` to the zeroth date. If you must replace NULL with empty string you must convert the date back to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can use the CONVERT command to format a date to a different format. You can try

```
select convert(varchar, datefield, 23)
```

which will convert your date to the wanted format (eg. 2006-12-30).

You could also use the FORMAT to do the same:

```
select format(datefield, 'dd-MM-yy') as date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your first suggestion was something I had tried previously. I'm unsure why, but this just retrieves the field as it is in the database, ie, DD/MMM/YYYY.

Comment: Probably you do need to use a different formatcode? I do think the second line is the better one, because you can really tell the system what pattern to use and do not use a "behind the scene" code.